# Arrange Data as per the Heading

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets, in spreadsheet 1, the headings are jumbled up. In spreadsheet 2, the headings are in the desired format.
I do it manually right now. I searched for the formula and tried various but no luck.

Is there any way that can arrange the data as per the desired headings ( as mentioned in Spreadsheet 2 )

Refer Screenshots:
Spreadsheet 1 (Jumbled data )

[image]

(Standard Format )Spreadsheet 2:

[image]

Thank you everyone in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, referencing the headings in `Spreadsheet 2` the data can be re-arranged accordingly as per the desired `Standard Format` that said, if one is using `MS365` then

• Using `CHOOSECOLS()` & `XMATCH()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, CHOOSECOLS(A2:G4,XMATCH(I1:O1,A1:G1)), IF(α=0,"",α))
```

---

Or, If Using `Excel 2021` then using `INDEX()`, `XMATCH()` with `SEQUENCE()` functions.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:G4, 
     _standardFormat, INDEX(_data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_data)),XMATCH(I1:O1,A1:G1)), 
     IF(_standardFormat=0,"",_standardFormat))
```

---

• For Older versions

[image]

---

```
=IF(INDEX($A$2:$G$4,ROW($ZZ1),MATCH(I$1,$A$1:$G$1,0))=0,"",
    INDEX($A$2:$G$4,ROW($ZZ1),MATCH(I$1,$A$1:$G$1,0)))
```

---

Comment: Hi Mayukh, Thank you for your response. Can we also get the headings arranged through this ?

Comment: As I have already mentioned above in the answer, I have used the headings of the Spreadsheet2 as a reference, hence you can also get the headings arranged by this method.